# Сделать чтобы анкета заполнялась на другом сайте html

Tags: html

Как сделать на своем сайте так, чтобы при заполнении анкеты она автоматически заполнялась на другом?

Comment: сформировать правильный post/get запрос (или их последовательность). Универсального решения нет, для каждого сайта нужно подгонять свое.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите какие параметры передаются на сайте - передавайте их туда на своем, главное, определитесь в результате чего отправляются данные формы. Как вариант прикрутите у себя OpenId и используйте любой из возможных аккаунтов как единый.

Comment: Если удаленный ресурс умеет работать и использует OpenId, естественно